# Symbolic nest expressions

Tags: symbolic, expression-manipulation, iteration

I'm trying to understand how to use symbolic expressions as arguments. The following example represents my problem:

```
Q[f_, s0_] := Q[f, s0] = D[f[s0], s0]
Q[Q[f, s0], s0]
```

where Q is simply first derivative of function f. As a result of the second line, I expect to see second derivative of f. But I'm getting

```
f'[s0]'[s0] + f''[s0][s0]
```

Could you help me please find a way to obtain a correct answer?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try using `Q[f_, s0_] := Q[f, s0] = D[f, s0]` in a fresh kernel, and then evaluate `Q[Q[f, s0], s0]` again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are effectively calling `Q` with two different argument patterns (`Q[foo, t]` in the first call in the nested calls and `Q[bar[t],t]` in the outer call) but your `Q` is defined only for the first argument pattern. If you add the definition for the second signature, you get the desired result:

```
ClearAll[Q]
Q[f_, s0_] := Q[f, s0] = D[f[s0], s0]
Q[f_[s0_], s0_] := Q[f, s0]

Q[Q[f, s0], s0]
```

> ```
>  (f^′′)[s0]
> ```

```
Q[Q[f[s0], s0], s0]
```

> ```
>   (f^′′)[s0]
> ```

Comment: That solves my problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you using [`Derivative`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative.html):

```
Q[f_] := Derivative[1][f]
Q[f_, s0_] := Derivative[1][f][s0]
```

```
Q[f, s0]
```

> ```
> f'[s0]
> ```

```
Q[Q[f], s0]
```

> ```
> f''[s0]
> ```

BTW, the number `1` in the first `[...]` after `Derivative` can be other integers, so that the nested application can actually be lifted.

Comment: That is a good solution! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Q[function_,variable_,n_? Positive]/;Element[n,Integers]:=Nest[D[#,variable]&,function[variable],n]
```

Example:

```
Q[f,s0,1]
Q[f,s0,2]
(*f'[s0]*)
(*f''[s0]*)
```