# Nest expressions of several arguments

Tags: expression-construction, iteration, arguments

I have the following function:

```
Q[r_, f_, s0_] := Q[r, f, s0] = F[r, s0] D[f[s0], s0]
```

By calling

```
Q[r, Q[r, f, s0], s0]
```

I obtain the following result:

```
F[r,s0] ((F[r,s0] f'[s0])'[s0]+(F[r,s0] f''[s0]+f'[s0] F^(0,1)[r,s0])[s0])
```

when the desired answer is

```
F[r,s0](F[r,s0] f''[s0]+f'[s0] F^(0,1)[r,s0])
```

Could you please help me to obtain the correct answer?

Thank you in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue and solution are similar to the one in [your previous post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/222639/125). In addition, we need to give `Q` the attribute [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html):

```
ClearAll[Q, f, F]
SetAttributes[Q, HoldAll]
Q[r_, f_, s0_] :=  Q[r, f, s0] = F[r, s0]  D[f[s0], s0]
Q[r_, f_[r_, g_, s0_], s0_] := F[r, s0] D[f[r, g, s0], s0]

Q[r, f, s0]
```

> ```
>  F[r,s0] (f^′)[s0]
> ```

```
Q[r, Q[r, f, s0], s0]
```

> ```
> F[r,s0] (F[r,s0] (f^′′)[s0]+(f^′)[s0] (F^(0,1))[r,s0])
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Svetlana, you are welcome. And welcome to mma.se.